# ActiveMQ Artemis equivalent to ActiveMQ Classic networkConnector with duplex

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there an equivalent to ActiveMQ Classic's `networkConnector` with `duplex` connection (bi-directional bridge) in ActiveMQ Artemis?

In core bridge I did not find duplex parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no equivalent to ActiveMQ Classic's `networkConnector` with `duplex` connection in ActiveMQ Artemis.